# Tomcat 6.0.10's org.apache.juli is empty

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

Anyone knows why Tomcat deliberately left some empty packages, including org.apache.juli, in catalina.jar?  I need org.apache.juli.logging.*, any idea where to find those classes?  Thanks

Comment: You should rather update your tomcat version. It is terribly old and has security flaws.

Comment: Ok, I solved the second question.  The package is in tomcat6/bin/tomcat-juli.jar.  But I still don't know why there are empty packages.

Comment: I've updated Tomcat to 7, and there are no more empty packages.  It seems they were just unfinished parts of Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

The available versions are:

```
juli-6.0.13.jar in org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.13
juli-6.0.13.jar in org/apache/tomcat/extras/juli/6.0.13
juli-6.0.14.jar in org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.14
juli-6.0.14.jar in org/apache/tomcat/extras/juli/6.0.14
juli-6.0.16.jar in org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.16
juli-6.0.16.jar in org/apache/tomcat/extras/juli/6.0.16
juli-6.0.18.jar in org/apache/tomcat/juli/6.0.18
juli-6.0.18.jar in org/apache/tomcat/extras/juli/6.0.18
```

Try one of those.